# Python basics, dataframe iteration - calculating average number of ratings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In dataframe I have columns such as prime_genre and user_rating. I want to calculate  average number of ratings (to do that i try to summarize ratings for each app and then divide by number of apps occurrences).
My solution looks like this:

```
total=0
len_genre=0
for genre in prime_genre:
    for i in iosfree['prime_genre']:
        if(i == genre):
            len_genre += 1
            total += iosfree.loc[iosfree['prime_genre']==i, 'user_rating']  
    print("Genre: ", genre, "Average rating: ", total/len_genre)
```

Result looks like this:

```
Genre:  Music Average rating:  0      NaN
5      NaN
43     NaN
48     NaN
51     NaN
```

Average rating shouldn't be zero.
Could you please give me some advice how to fix it? I am new to Python.

Comment: Add a small sample of the data you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can do with `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.groupby('prime_genre')['user_rating'].agg(['count','mean'])
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thank you a lot!